# InvalidCharacterError on Firefox (possibly other browsers)

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have the following line of Javascript code:

```
objRadioElement = document.createElement('<input type="radio" name="rdUserDefined8" value="basketball" class="UDFRadioClass" disabled>');
```

It is causing an `InvalidCharacterError` in Firefox (possibly other browsers, but I am having some debugging issues). Can anyone tell why?

Comment: you only put in the name of the element you want to create not the full tag, you can set the attributes of the element with functions on the `objRadioElement`, like `.setAttribute("AttributeName","Value")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.createElement` does not take an HTML string; it takes the name of the element you want to create:

```
var element = document.createElement('input');
element.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
// etc.
```

This is one reason why jQuery is handy; you can create an element with an HTML string like this:

```
var objRadioElement = $('<input type="radio" name="rdUserDefined8" value="basketball" class="UDFRadioClass" disabled>');
```

One shortcut you could take without jQuery is to create a container element, set its `innerHTML` property with your HTML string, then get the element from there:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="rdUserDefined8" value="basketball" class="UDFRadioClass" disabled>';
var radioElement = container.firstChild;
```